# How do you have a panel `ClipToBounds` without clipping children?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, custom-controls

I have a custom Panel implementation that renders objects relative to a physical space (think like a floor plan).  The panel allows the following actions:

- Zoom in/out
- Pan up/down/left/right
- and more that isn't relevant to this question

The panel lives in with several other elements on screen, and I need to make sure the custom panel's graphics don't spill over the navigation and other controls.

The problem is this:

> If the panel is set to clip, it clips the children *before* arranging them.

Let's say I have a circle in the floor plan and the user zooms in enough to make the circle bigger than the parent control.  The panel applies clipping to the circle as if it were placed dead center, then arranges the circle where it is supposed to be.  The end result is that the circle no longer looks like a circle and I have gaps in the image.

I need the clipping to be applied *after* arranging the elements, or only applied to the overall image as compiled by the children.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had the opposite problem of the question the OP had in his letter to Dr. WPF where [ClipToBounds = "Maybe"](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/12/28/cliptoboundsmaybe/)

If I override the `GetLayoutClip()` method in my control and return null, I essentially turn off clipping for the element.  However, since `ClipToBounds` is still true for my panel, the rendered item doesn't spill over the rest of the application.

In the base class for all items that will be added to my custom panel I have this:

```
protected override Geometry GetLayoutClip(Size layoutSlotSize)
{
    return null;
}
```

In my case this is exactly what I want.  I honestly want my layout clip to be based on the parent panel and not the child size (with no sense of location within the panel).